# How to limit number of characters in Field using Redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have Field input and my idea is to user can input only 15 characters.
After 15 characters I want not displaying anything in field. I have tried with **normalize** but not working. I'm checking with **value.length** and after 15 characters my state is not updating which is good but I can still entering characters. I want after 15 entered characters, if user put something not to show that in browser. Can anyone help me?

```
                   <Field
                        name={`name`}
                        placeholder='placeholder'
                        classes={classes}
                        component={this.component}
                        onChange={this.changeHandler}
                    />
                    changeHandler= (event) => { 
                      if(event.target.value.length < 16) 
                      {
                        this.setState({
                        myProperty: event.target.value
                        });
                      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For redux-form `Field` there isn't a props to limitate number of chars. Considering that you are using `Field` in a form, you could validate the field itself (using `validate` props as in [this](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/fieldlevelvalidation/) example) but still the possibility to add more than 15 chars.

But as you know you could customize your `Field` using `component` props. Something like:

```
<Field name="myField" component={renderField}/>
```

And  in `renderField` you could use `input` and in input you have `maxlength` props.

So your `renderField`  could be something like:

```
const renderField = (field) => (
    <div className="input-row">
      <input {...field.input} type="text" maxlength="15"/>
    </div>
  )
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! You solved my problem

Comment: Happy to ear that. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

For this you would need a handled value. Pass `value={this.state.myProperty}` to the Field. So if this property is no longer updated after 15 characters, the value of the field won't be updated either.